# Añadir Reporting Services 2016 a un grupo de alta disponibilidad (AG)

Tags: sql-server

Buenas, mi situación es la siguiente:

Tengo un cluster de conmutación por error creado con 3 nodos. Tengo una base de datos en dicho cluster, añadida al AG,  y funciona correctamente, replica los cambios y en caso de caída del nodo principal se activa uno de los secundarios.
Mi problema viene cuando quiero añadir las bases de datos de Reporting services (ReportServer y ReportServerTempdb) al grupo de alta disponibilidad de sql.
He probado de dos maneras diferentes:

- 1- He restaurado la base de datos del servidor de informes en el nodo
  principal y después he añadido las bases de datos al grupo de alta
  disponibilidad y me lo ha replicado en los 3 nodos sin aparente
  problema, pero cuando intento lanzar un informe solamente se muestra
  cuando en el cluster está activo el nodo primario que tenía las bases
  de datos de RS original. Al conmutar a otro nodo se muestra el
  siguiente error:

  ***El servidor de informes no pudo validar la integridad de los datos cifrados de la base de datos. (rsCannotValidateEncryptedData)]***
- 2- Otra forma que he probado es restaurando las bases de RS en los
  tres nodos y luego añadirlas posteriormente al grupo de alta
  disponibilidad. El problema que me encuentro aquí es que en caso de
  caída del nodo principal no conmuta a otro nodo, se produce un error
  indicando que no pudo levanta el nodo secundario y el error es
  provocado por la base de RS.

¿Sabéis alguna forma de añadir el servidor de informes a un grupo de alta disponibilidad?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

Buenas

Ya encontré la solución. Los pasos a seguir son los siguientes:

1. Restaurar una copia de las bases reportserver y reportserverTemp en
   el nodo principal del cluster.
2. Añadir las bases de datos al grupo de alta disponibilidad para que 
   se repliquen las bases de datos. (La replicación es correcta pero la
   clave de cifrado no lo es)
3. Crea una copia de la la clave de cifrado a través de RS
   Configuration Manager.
4. Restaurar dicha clave de cifrado en cada uno de los nodos de que
   componen el cluster, poniendo como primario cada nodo del cluster en
   el que restauramos la clave.

Con estos pasos he conseguido que funcione. He de indicar que instalé también el SP1 de sql server 2016 que trae alguna mejora relacionado con reporting services.